# Java 8 default method interface override Object equals method

Tags: java, java-8, default-method

```
public interface Table<T> {

    @Overrride
    default boolean equals(Object other) {
        //do something and return true/false
    }
}
```

Why does the above code has compilation error of "java: default method equals in interface Table overrides a member of java.lang.Object"? Can't we override hashCode and equals method using interface default method, presumably I have methods in the same interface to determine the equality of the object implementing this interface?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No.  Classes with implementations always win over default methods, so having a default `hashCode` or `equals` can never be invoked and therefore is forbidden.

Comment: Not only *implementations* win over default methods. *Any declaration* made in a non-`interface` class (i.e. within the superclass hierarchy) wins, even if it is declared `abstract`.

Comment: Agree with Holger, this is a bug.  If I know I have interface methods and a reasonable toString default implementation calling those methods is possible, I should be allowed to declare on in an interface.  Unsure what should happen if multiple interfaces declare default implementations, what happens now?